# How use LF for line endings in Zend Studio 8/9  or on Eclipse on Windows 7

Tags: eclipse, newline, zend-studio

I need to use unix Style line endings (only LF) in Zend Studio 8/9 or in Eclipse on Windows, how should i do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create new files with Unix line endings, set Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > New text file line delimiter > Unix.

To convert existing line endings to Unix style, do File > Convert Line Delimiters to > Unix.

**UPDATE**: This conversion also works on whole projects if you select the project in project view before doing File > Convert Line Delimiters to > Unix. Binary files are, at least in my tests, not affected by this mass-conversion.

Comment: Yes i discovered that long ago but never remembered to answer this :)